# How to determine if the type is one of the Action/Func delegates?

Tags: c#, types

Other than doing this is there a better way to determine whether type is a one of the Action<> delegates.

```
if(obj is MulticastDelegate && obj.GetType().FullName.StartsWith("System.Action"))
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: "type" here is not a type object, but rather an instance of the object whose type is in question?  That seems like a very misleading thing to name the variable.

Comment: @Eric: You are right, I was trying something, normally I would not name it like that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This seems perfectly straightforward.

```
static bool IsAction(Type type)
{
    if (type == typeof(System.Action)) return true;
    Type generic = null;
    if (type.IsGenericTypeDefinition) generic = type;
    else if (type.IsGenericType) generic = type.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
    if (generic == null) return false;
    if (generic == typeof(System.Action<>)) return true;
    if (generic == typeof(System.Action<,>)) return true;
    ... and so on ...
    return false;
}
```

I'm curious as to why you want to know this though. What do you care if a particular type happens to be one of the versions of Action? What are you going to do with that information?

Comment: I am playing with a "Clay" library, and  I want to attach Action/Func type properties to dynamic  Clay objects. Long story..

Comment: Is it enough to check for `type.BaseType == typeof(MulticastDelegate)`?

Comment: @AshleyF: I'm not following your line of thought here. The question is about identifying action and func delegates, not about identifying any delegate. Can you clarify the question?]

Answer (score 3):

```
 private static readonly HashSet<Type> _set = new HashSet<Type>
     {
         typeof(Action), typeof(Action<>), typeof(Action<,>),    // etc
         typeof(Func<>), typeof(Func<,>), typeof(Func<,,>),      // etc
     };

 // ...

 Type t = type.GetType();
 if (_set.Contains(t) ||
     (t.IsGenericType && _set.Contains(t.GetGenericTypeDefinition())))
 {
     // yep, it's one of the action or func delegates
 }
```